# How to add a 'where' condition to 'execution.getData' in a gooddata-js API

Tags: gooddata

I'm using  [gooddata-js API](https://github.com/gooddata/gooddata-js) and I need some help to include **'where'** condition into **'execution.getData'** method.
For example: I need compare a date month/year attribut like **[/gdc/md/{PROJECT_ID}/obj/OBJ_ID] = [/gdc/md/{PROJECT_ID}/obj/OBJ_ID/elements?id=24235]**

I tried use the condition below but didn't work!

```js
sdk.execution.getData(projectId, elements,'[/gdc/md/{PROJECT_ID}/obj/OBJ_ID] = [/gdc/md/{PROJECT_ID}/obj/OBJ_ID/elements?id=24235]').then(function(dataResult){

     var headers = dataResult.headers.map(function (h) {
            return h.title;
     });
     var data1 = dataResult.rawData;
}'
```

I expect receive data into **dataResult.headers**, but the **dataResult.rawData** is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according GooddataJS documentation, 3rd param of getData method is executionConfiguration object
https://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-js/api/classes/execution.html#method_getData

so I can imagine, that something like:

```
{
    where: {
        "/gdc/md/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/obj/YOUR_DATE_DATASET_ID": {
            "$between":[-1,-1],
            "$granularity":"GDC.time.year"
        }
    }
}
```

would apply date filter during execution, or

```
{
    where: {
        "/gdc/md/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/obj/YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_DISPLAY_FORM_ID": {
            "$in":[{
                "id":"/gdc/md/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/obj/YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_ID/elements?id=SELECTED_ATTRIBUTE_ELEMENT_ID"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

would apply positive attribute filter